# Install GIMP (The following packages have unmet dependencies)

Tags: apt, dependencies, gimp, aptitude

Trying to install GIMP with apt-get install gimp when I get this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.8.16) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.8.16-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not installable
        Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get remove <package name>
```

Also `sudo apt-get install aptitude`
and then `sudo aptitude install gimp`
wich gives:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gimp{b} gimp-data{a} libbabl-0.1-0{a} libgimp2.0{ab} libmng2{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 15,1 MB of archives. After unpacking 68,3 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14) but 1.6.18-0ubuntu4.3 is installed.
        Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) which is a virtual package.
        Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is installed.
 libgimp2.0 : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gimp [Not Installed]                               
2)     libgimp2.0 [Not Installed]                         

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
3)     gimp-data recommends gimp                          


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

*Enters y*:

```
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

what to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Which package name did you put in `sudo apt-get remove <package name>`???

Comment: All of the packages with unmet dependencies, starting from the top.